# Insertion in Circular Linked List (output not coming as desired)

Tags: c, linked-list, insertion, circular-list

This is the method I wrote in C. It is for insertion in a linked list.

```
void insert_beg()
{
temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
ptr=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

int data_value;

printf("Enter the value\n");
scanf("%d",&data_value);

temp->info=data_value;

if(header->link==NULL)//when there is no node
{
    header->link=temp;
    temp->link=header;
}
else//when atleast one node has been created
{
    ptr->link=header->link;//ptr is pointing to where header was pointing.
    header->link=temp;
    temp->link=header;
}

printf("\n\n");
}
```

This is the code for traversal (basically display)

```
 void traverse()
{
ptr=header->link;

while(ptr->link!=header)
{
    ptr=ptr->link;
    printf("%d\t",ptr->info);
}
printf("\n\n");
}
```

When running the program, the output for traversal is nothing. It's as if the for loop is not running. There is no segmentation fault when inserting or any other thing.
Is my logic correct? If not, then where am I going wrong?

Comment: I think the condition should be `if (header == NULL)`. Then `temp->link = ptr->link`. Otherwise you'd loose original `header->link`

Comment: in the `insert_beg` function, why are two objects of `node` being created ?

Comment: @PRP when I removed the ptr object, then a problem with the else part of the code arise. I was getting a segmentation fault. So that's why..

Answer (score 1):

The original `header->link` value is getting lost because of wrong assignments.
Also you do not need to `malloc` for variable `ptr`. Modify your if/else block.

```
if (header == NULL){
    header = temp
    header->link = temp
}
else//when atleast one node has been created
{
    ptr=header->link;//ptr is pointing to where header was    pointing.
    header->link=temp;
    temp->link=ptr;
}
```

Basically you are always trying to add at the second position with your `else block` but instead of putting the old data to third place you are pointing your second back to head.

I also see some fundamental problems with the above code. The code neither accepts a pointer variable nor it returns any pointer. Once the function returns, there is no way to access the data.

If header is a global variable then this should be the change. `malloc` of `temp` and everything else associated with `temp` should move inside the `else` block as we do not need them for `if` part

```
if (header->link == NULL){
    header->data = data
    header->link = header
}
```

If header isn't a global variable then to solve the complete problem, function should be modified as

```
void insert_beg(struct node **header_dptr) #A double pointer
{
   header = *header_dptr
   temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   int data_value;

   printf("Enter the value\n");
   scanf("%d",&data_value);

   temp->info=data_value;

   if(header==NULL)//when there is no node
   {
       header=temp;
       header->link=temp;
   }
  else//when atleast one node has been created
  {
       ptr=header->link;//ptr is pointing to where header was    pointing.
       header->link=temp;
       temp->link=ptr;
  }

printf("\n\n");
}
```

Comment: can we do `temp->link = header->link; header->link = temp;` to avoid a temporary pointer ?

Comment: Yes we can do that but I have retained the original code so that the OP understands the bug in the original code.

Comment: @Sharad I'm getting a segmentation fault with this code. (on traversal). Also, what is the difference between header->link=temp and header=temp?I'm sorry if that sounds dumb but I'm really confused right now.

Comment: Can you add where are you initializing the `header` variable ? You should either accept a pointer variable (header preferably) or return a pointer variable in your function. Otherwise there won't be any way to access the date

Comment: @Sharad I've made a main method and created a menu-based system using switch case which runs on a condition using a do-while loop. The header node is initialised outside all the methods and the memory is allotted to it in the main method.

Comment: @Sindhugauri Check the code change that I have done. I hope that should solve your issue

Comment: I think in OPs program `header` is declared as global variable

Comment: @CherubimAnand Assuming that OP has used global variable,  am providing another solution.